# CommandLink with action support visual force page

Tags: apex, visualforce, actionsupport, apex-param

I want to pass the value of the pressed link to the controller - Is that possible with

`<apex:actionsupport >`? 
Or should I use the apex:param for this?

```
 <apex:column style="float:right;">
  <apex:commandLink value="{!acc.name}" reRender="accountId,selectedProductListId" action="{!proceedToUpload}" oncomplete="closeTable();"> 
        <apex:param value="{!acc.Id}" name="act" />
        <apex:param value="{!acc.Name}" name="accountName" />

      </apex:commandLink>

   </apex:column>

 </apex:pageBlockTable>
```

I want to know if I can do it on the same way like in the apex:selectList:

```
<apex:selectList styleClass="form-control" size="1" value="{!productSelected}" id="selectedProductListId">
                                        <apex:selectOptions value="{!productoList}" id="selectOptionsProductId"/>
                                        <apex:actionSupport action="{!checkTheValues}" event="onchange" reRender="selectedProductItemListId" />
                                    </apex:selectList>
```

and then I will have the value: 'productSelected' on the controller after the apex:supportAction ran without using the apex:param...

(and of course I will have  'productSelected' variable with get;set; inside the controller)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't pass the `value` to the controller; it's the attribute that shows the label. You can use the `apex:param` either directly or within the `apex:actionSupport` element. The only change you need to make to your code is to create public variables, and use the `assignTo` attribute to assign the values:

## Apex

```
public transient string accountId { get; set; }
public transient string accountName { get; set; }
```

## Visualforce

```
<apex:param value="{!acc.Id}" name="var1" assignTo="{!accountId}" />
<apex:param value="{!acc.Name}" name="var2" assignTo="{!accountName}" />
```

Comment: Hi @sfdcfox, Thanks for answering.
I just updated the question - if you can look on it.
I did it as you said, I just wanted to know if I can give up on the apex:param...

Comment: @Salvation You will need an apex:param, there's no other way to get parameters back to the controller.